# Hadoop streaming php environmental variables

Tags: php, hadoop

How can I get the input filename in mapper using php?

Comment: Is my question unclear? I dont really understand why I am getting down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://blog.mayflower.de/archives/562-An-introduction-to-Hadoop.html), for php the template for map-reduce is :

```
01  function map ($filename, $content) {
02      foreach (explode('', $content) as $word) {
03          collect($word, 1);
04      }
05  }
06   
07  function reduce($word, $values) {
08      $numWordCount = 0;
09   
10      foreach ($values as $value) {
11          $numWordCount += $value;
12      }
13   
14      collect($word, $numWordCount);
```

Now, can't the value of `$filename` be [printed inside a php function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)  ?